# How do I send data from a child worker process to parent process?

Tags: elixir

I have 2 modules, one is the supervisor and the other is its worker. I have calculated something in the 2nd (child) module, how do I send that value to the parent (supervisor) module?

```elixir
defmodule VampSupervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link(init_arg) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, init_arg)
  end

  def init(init_arg) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    [start,last] = init_arg
    nodes = Enum.chunk_every(start..last, 10)
    children = Enum.map(nodes, fn(chunk_list) ->
      worker(FACT, [chunk_list], [id: List.first(chunk_list), restart: :permanent])
    end)
    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end

defmodule FACT do
  use GenServer
  def start_link(init_arg) do
         pid = spawn_link(__MODULE__,:init,[init_arg])
    {:ok,pid}
  end

  def init(init_arg) do
    Enum.each(init_arg, fn(x)->
      spawn(__MODULE__,:main,[x])
    end)
  end

 def main(n) do
    list = make_factor(n,round(:math.sqrt(n)),[])
    {:ok,pid}=GenServer.start_link(VampServer, list)
    Enum.each(list, fn(_)->
      {x,[head,tail]} = GenServer.call(pid,{:check_vampire,n})
      if x==n do
        IO.puts("#{x} #{head} #{tail}") **This has be sent back to supervisor**
      end
    end)
end
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using to setup the supervision tree? Also, the code to give a worker a job, etc. would be helpful too.

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf here's the code

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues with your approach.

1. [`Supervisor.Spec.supervisor/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.Spec.html?#supervisor/3) and [`Supervisor.Spec.worker/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.Spec.html?#worker/3) are **deprecated** and should be avoided; one should use [child specs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.html#module-child-specification) instead.
2. [`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.html) is not meant to receive *user callbacks*. The only callback it has is [`Supervisor.init/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.html#c:init/1). The processes that are supposed to receive user messages are to be made workers.
3. You abuse `GenServer` for doing the simple function call in `VampServer`.

Instead of this

```
{:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(VampServer, list)
Enum.each(list, fn _ ->
  GenServer.call(pid, {:check_vampire, n})
end)
```

one should implement a plain old good function `Vamp.check_vampire/1` and call it explicitly instead, like

```
Enum.each(list, fn _ ->
  Vamp.check_vampire(n)
end)
```

[`GenServer.call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html?#call/3) is synchronous and does [almost] exactly what the plain function would do.

---

The summing up. Start a `VampSupervisor` as `Supervisor` with two workers: `FACT` that will do calculations and `FACTConsumer` that will receive messages from `FACT` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a supervisor and workers to do some transient work and then report back.

Normally, you start `Supervisor` and `DynamicSupervisor` within your application tree, and these supervisors get *named* so you can refer to them across the node just by their name. These supervisors are meant to be long-lived, and are probably not a good fit for your use case.

A better solution might be to try [`Task.async/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#module-async-and-await). (See also [the guides](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html#tasks) on `Task`.) This will let you fire off a bunch of computations in parallel and have them join back together.

Alternatively, you can define a module to spin up tasks that are supervised under a [`TaskSupervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html), which get the caller's pid with `self()` when created. However, I think `Task.async/1` might be your best option in this case.